# php: how to check user logged in or not from download server?

Tags: php

I have two server, First one main server (database stored here) and second one is download server (files stored in it), I want limit download links only for registered users in download server.
In download server how can I check if users logged in or not? and if logged in is account expired or not?
I'm using php.
thanks...

Comment: not really enough info: Try setting up a mysql db, and have users setup and account and login through that, if user in DB then they are logged in, if not, then no link

Comment: without existing code nobody will be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved this:

All links to the download server would point to the main server instead.
The main server would check for login, then generate a key for the user storing that key in the user's db table. Then redirect the user to the download server including the generated key string and user id in the redirect link to the download server. The download server would make a call to an API on the main server. The API would run a query against the id & key string and return a success|fail response. Upon success the download server would deliver the resource and the main server would NULL the key field in the user's table.

You would need 3 files:
1) main server/link.php - checks log in, updates key, redirects to download server. 
2) download server/resource.php - calls API to check access, delivers content.
2) main server/api.php - confirms access, NULLs out used key.

Comment: You would need a: